# react native webview domain undefined code -2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im new in react native im trying to use webview but i got this error

> Encountered an error loading page {"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "code": -2, "description": "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED", "loading": false, "target": 69, "title": "", "url": "https://github.com/facebook/react-native"}

ver :

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-webview": "^8.0.1"
```

},

code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any fix?